# Add Reward Points in product list in category section of Opencart

Tags: opencart

Category page -before customization
[image]

we have to take reward points from the category page like this----
[image]

and show that reward point from product page to category page.

So, the category page must look like this after customization----
[image]

I am trying it out from 1 month and also googled about it several times but didn't get the required solution.

If someone have any idea about it, please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, by saying this *I am trying it out from 1 month and also googled about it several times but didn't get the required solution.* you are only telling on yourself... Instead of giving up and asking for help with tail down between the legs you should share the code that you have tried - maybe you were missing only some stupid thing that we could point out directly and you could learn more from personal lesson. Now we all just think something about you what may not be true...

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying it out from 1 month and also googled about it several
>   times but didn't get the required solution.

The view for that page is: `catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.tpl`

As you can see, it has a javascript function called `display(view)` that let intact the design even if you add code

To do that you have to modify two files

1. `catalog\controller\product\category.php`
2. `catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.tpl`

**Edit the file 1**

Search this line:

```php
'name'        => $result['name'],
```

Around the line `241`

Add these line bellow:

```php
'model'       => $result['model'],
'points'      => $result['points'],
```

Save file

**Now edit the file 2**

Search this line:

```php
<div class="description"><?php echo $product['description']; ?></div>
```

Around the line `76`

Add these lines bellow:

```php
<div class="model"><strong>Model: <?php echo $product['model']; ?></strong></div>
<div class="points"><strong>Reward Points: <?php echo $product['points']; ?></strong></div>
```

Now search for this line:

```js
html += '  <div class="description">' + $(element).find('.description').html() + '</div>';
```

Around the line `139`

Add these lines bellow:

```js
html += '  <div class="model">' + $(element).find('.model').html() + '</div>';
html += '  <div class="points">' + $(element).find('.points').html() + '</div>';
```

Here the proof

[image]